# What is a valid mapping from the simplex to positive orthant of sphere?

Tags: spheres, simplex

Where the simplex is all points such that the sum of entries is 1, and the sphere is all points such that the squared sum of entries is 1.

Where the norm is given by Fisher metric:

$$||\dot X_t||_{X_t}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (\dot X_t)_i^2 / (X_t)_i$$

To find mapping from:
$$\Delta = \left\{x \Bigg| x_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1\right\}$$

To the positive orthant of the sphere:
$$S = \left\{y \Bigg| y_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 = 1\right\}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Some edits would be helpful for you to get useful responses: The current title is OK (though _valid_ is not a widely used technical term in this context; a more descriptive term would clarify). The question body should contain the complete question; the fact that it doesn't probably accounts for the vote to close. As for the question, are you asking about a real simplex? Open or closed? Do you want a continuous mapping? A continuous bijection? Is this homework (and if so, what type of course, what have you tried, what tools are available), or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: divide by the square root of the sum of squares.  Explicitly, define $f:\Delta \to S$ by $$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\frac{(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}}.$$
Now show that $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in S$.

Comment: possible to elaborate a bit.. would the division be over the norm squared

Comment: You probably need the square root in the denominator, to normalise properly.

Comment: @MaciejS. Indeed! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give the correct answer: **scale by the euclidean norm**.

The unit sphere is just the set of vectors of unit length. So enough to scales vectors by their lengths

$$f(x) = x / \|x\|_2,$$

recall that $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^2}$.